# WPF Popup Panel take needed space

Tags: wpf, frontend

I'm having an issue making a popup notification panel take only the amount of space it's inner controls require.

What I've Got:

```
 <Grid>
    <DockPanel Panel.ZIndex="1111" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding MessageVisibility}">
        <Button Visibility="Collapsed" Name="clickButton" Command="{Binding Path=CloseMessage}"/>
        <Border Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="20" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" BorderThickness="8" BorderBrush="CadetBlue">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20px">
                <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding FallbackValue='Message'}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                </ItemsControl>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel  Panel.ZIndex="0">
...
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to make the first DockPanel only take up the space required by the ItemsControl. It seems to be taking the whole space.  Setting a Width/Heigh will keep it in the center but it will not let it grow.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from DockPanel to Stackpanel and setting Hor/Vert alignment center worked.

Answer (score 0):

The below modified code might be helpful and solve your pro

```
<Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
                <RowDefinition/>            
                <RowDefinition/>            
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>          
             <ColumnDefinitions/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>          

    <DockPanel Panel.ZIndex="1111" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding MessageVisibility}">
        <Button Visibility="Collapsed" Name="clickButton" Command="{Binding Path=CloseMessage}"/>
        <Border Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="20" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" BorderThickness="8" BorderBrush="CadetBlue">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20px">
                <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding FallbackValue='Message'}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                </ItemsControl>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel  Panel.ZIndex="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
...
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```